# How to infer return type based on return type of function in parameters

Tags: typescript

I have the following function in my app:

```
const store = createStore(
  { value: false },
  (set, get) => ({
     changeValue: (newValue: boolean) => {
       set((state) => { state.value = newValue })
     }
  })
)
```

I'm trying to get it so the type of the resulting `store` is:

```
{ value: boolean, changeValue: (newValue: boolean) => void }
```

without having to manually add the types. I feel like There should be a way to infer the types from the args of `createStore` within that function but I can't figure it out.

Here is what my `createStore` currently looks like:

```
export const createStore = <Document extends Record<string, unknown>>(
  document: Document,
  actions: () => Record<string, unknown>,
) => {
  return Object.assign({}, document, actions())
}

const test = createStuff({ hello: 'world' }, () => ({ update: () => 'test' }))
```

In this case the type of `test` is

```
{
    hello: string;
} & Record<string, unknown>
```

and I would like it to be:

```
{
    hello: string;
} & { update: () => string }
```

Comment: Is this `createStore` from redux?  Or is this something of your own creation?

Comment: It’s something custom, I was pretty sure the internals were not relevant, but I suppose I could be wrong.

Comment: I mean you're talking about inferring the return type of a function ` createStore`, but you haven't shared that function with us, or what it actually returns.  We need to see `createStore` to be able to help.

Comment: ok, I added an example of what createStore looks like above

Answer (score 0):

You've correctly leveraged using `Document extends Record<string, unknown>` to create a generic, where the return value includes whatever argument you put for the first argument `document`.  Now you just need to do the same thing for the `actions` argument.  It would look something like this:

```
const createStore = <Document extends Record<string, unknown>, ActionReturn>(
    document: Document,
    actions: () => ActionReturn,
) => {
    return Object.assign(document, actions())
}

const test = createStore({ hello: 'world' }, () => ({ update: () => 'test' }))
```

Now the value of `test` is typed as:

```
const test: {
    hello: string;
} & {
    update: () => "test";
}
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMBOBTAhlRBlKIkwLwwB4AREYAVwFtExZEAPNMAEwhgCVFR4mDp4BLMAHMANDDJgA1mBAB3MAD4xAQWBR+4DlDLxFACgBQMYzCalK1KAC4YJclRoijJ5Go2QbegJR4FMVeqaiNq6Tj64fgDezsZIIWAwAPIARgBWnFAAdMgQEPxCYHpm9pZiroGQ3l4GAL4GBqCQsGjQeHBIqBhYSHqRMAAWiAA2QyA2AOSy2ENM4zA1Yt6+ML3iAA5MnZ7hfuMtUHM1Xl5AA)